# Tranfinite induction, 0.9...=1

Tags: sequences-and-series, transfinite-induction

Can transfinite induction be used to demonstrate that 0.9...=1?

More generally, can it be used to prove limits of sequences?

Comment: Elementary analysis already proves that the series $9\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, transfinite induction is not designed for this job.

The job that transfinite induction is designed for is to prove universally quantified statements of the form

> For all $x \in \omega$, $P(x)$ is true

where $\omega$ is a well-ordered set. In ordinary induction $\omega$ is the natural numbers, in transfinite induction $\omega$ can be a more general well-ordered set.

But the equation $.999... = 1$, which translates into the equation 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{9}{10^i} = 1
$$
is not a universally quantifed statement of the required form for transfinite induction. It is, of course, a universally quantified statement of a different sort:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that if $n \in \mathbb N$ and if $n \ge N$ then $\left| 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{9}{10^i} \right| = 0$.

but there's not any way (that I can see) to twist this into an equivalent form that matches the form of transfinite induction.

Comment: Thanks- I had someone try and tell me that transfinitw induction could be used in lieu of limits. I had a "that doesnt sound right, but I dont know enough to disagree" moment.

Comment: It helps to write out the statements in fully quantified form, and you can see that they are just different.

Answer (score 1):

Sequences and series such as the one we use for $0.999\ldots=1$ all have the same infinite length, so there isn't anywhere to "transfinitely induct" *to.*

Moreover, we already use ordinary finite induction to prove limits of sequences.

So I really don't see how transfinite induction applies here.